# The integral $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{L_m(-x)}{e^{2 \pi x}+1} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you expain the following sum I seen in a forum
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{L_m(-x)}{e^{2 \pi  x}+1} \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(2^{-2 n-1} \left(2^n-1\right) \pi ^{-n-1} \zeta (n+1)\right) \binom{m}{n}$$where L in a Lagarre polinomium

Comment: Very interesting indeed. :D

Comment: Please, make titles more informative and less subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result follows from a simple, explicit expression for the Laguerres:

$$L_m(-x) = \sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

The integral is then

$$\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n} \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^n}{e^{2\pi x}+1}$$

Now, each integral is easily evaluated in terms of the zeta function by expanding the denominator:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{x^n}{e^{2\pi x}+1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \int_0^{\infty} dx\, x^n \, e^{-(k+1) 2\pi x}\\ &= \frac{n!}{(2\pi)^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^{n+1}} \\ &=  \frac{n!}{(2 \pi)^{n+1}} \left (1-\frac{1}{2^n} \right ) \zeta(n+1)\end{align}$$

The sum is then

$$\sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n} \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{n+1}} \left (1-\frac{1}{2^n} \right ) \zeta(n+1)$$

Note that $\binom{m}{n} = 0$ when $n \gt m$, so the infnite sum presented in the question is actually a finite sum.